# CSCvg76186 - Cisco Smart Install Remote Code Execution and Denial of Service Vulnerability

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, ios-xe, bug

If you missed this Catastrophic severity 1 vulnerability, check the temporary solution below, if you do not want to upgrade your software to a not properly tested software. There are currently, at the time of writing, no software upgrade solution available to the whole 3560 series switches.

Cisco Advisory:

https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20180328-smi2

Cisco Bug 76186 description (requires login)

https://bst.cloudapps.cisco.com/bugsearch/bug/CSCvg76186

In dept description:

https://thehackernews.com/2018/04/cisco-switches-hacking.html

If you do not use Smart Install, will it prevent the vulnerability if Smart Install is disabled?

Hopefully there will be some proper software upgrades available soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can hereby confirm that, disabling Smart Install will prevent this vulnerability.

Before disabling:

```
X@X:/mnt/c/Python$ python vstack.py -t 172.26.23.250
[*] Connecting to Smart Install Client  172.26.23.250 port 4786
[*] Send a malicious packet
```

After this switch crashes and reloads.

Then i use `no vstack` in global config mode and try again:

```
X@X:/mnt/c/Python$ python vstack.py -t 172.26.23.250
[*] Connecting to Smart Install Client  172.26.23.250 port 4786
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vstack.py", line 32, in <module>
    con.connect((options.target, options.port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

We've implemented no vstack on 3000 switches, since we do not use Smart Install.

Comment: Exactly. We have had to disable this for a while, and it pops up again every once in a while.